# Supporting multiple metrics via prometheus (statsd and prometheus)

Tags: java, spring, metrics, statsd, micrometer

I am in the middle of moving the metrics collection system from statsd to Prometheus. It is a spring boot app and based on a micrometer. I am wondering if there is a way to start supporting both hierarchical statsd metrics and also dimensional Prometheus metrics at the same time.

Currently, the way I create a timer is

```
Metrics.timer("apiName.endpointName.latency").record(latency)
```

This is fine for statsd but does not work for Prometheus. I need to support a separate metric with tags such as

```
service_latency {api="apiName", endpoint="endpointName"}
```

Is it possible to support both at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can support both at the same time. The recommended way is

```
Metrics.timer("latency", Tags.of("api", apiName, "endpoint", endpointName.)).record(latency)
```

Then use a 'hierarchical [naming convention](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_naming_meters)'

That way the statsd tags are placed in the hierarchy as you need them, and the Prometheus metrics are already tagged and ready to be used.

### Alternative (not recommended)

An alternative (and less appealing approach) would be to duplicate the meter between the 2 meter repositories.

Currently when you use `Metrics.timer("myMeter")` you are using the global composite meter registry, which delegates the meters to the underlying registries.

Instead if you call each registry individually:

```
statsdRegistry.timer("myMeter")...
prometheusRegistry.timer("myMeter")...
```

Unfortunately that will require more manual changes on your part and a duplication of code between the registries. But, you DO have that as an option.

Comment: This makes sense. My question is: in case of statsD, would ```Metrics.timer("latency", Tags.of("api", apiName, "endpoint", endpointName.)).record(latency)
``` produce metric like latency.apiName.endpointName or apiName.endpointName.latency

Comment: The [HierarchicalNameMapper](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/0dc111d1f6d3aa288dda24ac0912cbb483f1da1e/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/util/HierarchicalNameMapper.java) controls that. So you'll be able to customize it to match your needs.

I haven't used it myself though so I don't have a handy snippet for you

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I am using the statsd registry that spring autoconfigures once i add the dependency. But when i add tags to Metrics.timer(..) they get lots, so the metric name for the above example ends up just being `latency`. Could not find what name mapper the autoconfigured one uses. Any ideas? And how can i override it?